# QueryClose form event equivalent in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb6, vb6-migration

I'm migrating a VB6 application, which has a subroutine that fires upon a [`QueryClose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445535%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) form event.  As far as I can tell, this event no longer exists in [`System.Windows.Forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

I tested with a breakpoint, and `QueryClose` does fire when you click the red 'X' in the upper right corner of the VB6 form, like the [`FormClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx) event is supposed to do in VB.NET forms.

My question is: Does `FormClosing` have the closest equivalent functionality to `QueryClose`, or should I use a different event?

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(ByRef Cancel As Integer, ByRef CloseMode As Integer)
    writeToLog()
    writeRecentFoldersToFile(myTempFilePath & "Recent Folders.txt")
    writePageSetupDefaultsToFile(myTempFilePath & "Page Setup.txt")
    writeFormPositionToFile(myTempFilePath & "Form Position.txt")
    userformKillTimer(Me, Me.Text)
End Sub
```

*This code was originally VBA / VB6, which I put through ArtinSoft's Visual Basic Upgrade Companion (VBUC).  VBUC apparently didn't think that there is an equivalent event, or isn't smart enough to do that sort of conversion.  FWIW, I'm using Microsoft Visual Basic 2010 Express.*

Comment: VBA is not VB6. VBA has no forms anyway, Perhaps you really mean Excel? VBA only has life within its host. VB6 has no QueryClose in a Form, only in DataReports. *Is* this a DataReport? Or perhaps you mean QueryUnload? Don't overtag/mis-tag such posts. There should not even *be* a VBA tag, but instead tags such as Excel-VBA, Access-VBA, etc. since they all swim in different waters.

Comment: Well, it was originally VBA -- a macro for AutoCAD.  I had to port the forms _(or whatever you'd call them)_ over to VB6 first, before I could convert them into VB.NET.

Comment: @BobRiemersma: Ofcourse VBA has UserForms, may be slightly different from that of in VB6.

Comment: I think the OP meant QueryUnload, not QueryClose

Comment: No, *Excel* has UserForms, as do some other hosts. But VBA itself is just a macro language that requires a host exposing an object model if you're to have much of a GUI. Access is such a host and it has a Form but no UserForm.  There is no reason to expect any of them to have the same members as a VB6 Form.

Comment: It is indeed QueryClose -- I have the source code.  It was originally a macro in AutoCAD, written many years ago in the built-in VBAIDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put your code in FormClosed()

Your code doesn't allow the user to cancel the form close, all it does is save some data.

Comment: I don't know how I missed that event in the properties -- thanks!

Comment: Form.Shown is another good one if you want stuff to happen after the form has been created and displayed, but before the user starts clicking things.

Answer (score 2):

I would say to use FormClosing it is the closest thing to what you are used to. Raise a MessageBox to prompt if there is something to be cleaned up, then continue or abort the Close accordingly.